# Can't use Ctrl+A and Ctrl+E (bash keybindings) on Terminal.app OSX

Tags: macos, bash, key-bindings

So for some odd reason, i can't use ^A and ^E on bash in Terminal.app, i can however, use ^C, ^R, ^Y, ^L and all sort of other key bindings.

bind -p shows 
"\C-a": beginning-of-line
"\C-e": end-of-line

so i think something else is obstructing these key bindings...
any idea how i can fix that? or at least know if ^A and ^E are being taken by some other app?

highly appreciated

Comment: What do <Ctrl><V><Ctrl><A> and <Ctrl><V><Ctrl><E> show?

Comment: are you certain you're running bash? try `echo $SHELL` to see. I had a similar problem in zsh.

Comment: it was bash... anyway, i had to change machines so i lost interests in fixing this problem :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I must note the following:
Ctrl+Alt+A and Ctrl+Alt+E seem to do what Ctrl+A and Ctrl+E should do.

So when i run "read" on my terminal:
Ctrl+Alt+A shows: ^A and Ctrl+Alt+E shows: ^E ... 
note that Ctrl+R shows: ^R and Ctrl+Y shows ^Y just fine (these are just some examples).

i checked System Preferences, couldn't find the assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Check in System Preferences -> Keyboard pane -> Keyboard Shortcuts tab.  You'll have to look through all of the various categories listed in the left-hand pane to see if ^A and ^E are assigned anywhere.  (Note: you van also assign keyboard shortcuts in Terminal's preferences, but these seem not apply to basic alpha keys, just F-keys, arrows, etc.)